# sql hierarchy in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

i use postgres 9.5.
I need to store a (tree like) data like this :

- level 1a

  - level 2a

    - level 3a
    - level 3b
  - level 2b
- level 1b

  - level 2a
  - level 2b
- level 1c
- level 1d

this is my sql table:

`CREATE TABLE matieres_test (
    id serial NOT NULL CONSTRAINT matieres_test_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar NOT NULL,
    parent INT DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT matieres_test_parent_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES matieres_test(id)
);`

and insert ( the tabulation if for easy reading )

```
insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (1,'level 1a',null);
    insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (5,'level 2a ',1);
        insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (9,'level 3a',5);
        insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (10,'level 3b',5); 
    insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (6,'level 2b', 1);

insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (2,'level 1b',null);
    insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (7,'level 2a',2);
    insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (8,'level 2b',2); 

insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (3,'level 1c',null);
insert into matieres_test(id,name,parent) values (4,'level 1d',null);
```

---

NOW i want to get the data, my query :

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM matieres_test AS t1
LEFT JOIN matieres_test AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
LEFT JOIN matieres_test AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
LEFT JOIN matieres_test AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
```

the results :

```
    |   lev1    |  lev2     |   lev3
----|-----------|-----------|----------    
 1  |  level 1a | level 2a  | level 3b  
 2  |  level 1a | level 2a  | level 3a  
 3  |  level 2a | level 3b  |
 4  |  level 1b | level 2b  |
 5  |  level 1a | level 2b  |
 6  |  level 1b | level 2a  |
 7  |  level 2a | level 3a  |
 8  |  level 3b |
 9  |  level 2b |
 10 |  level 2b |
 11 |  level 2a |
 12 |  level 1d |
 13 |  level 1c |
 14 |  level 3a |
```

---

The problem is it return wrong lines (line 3,7,8,9,10,11,14)
because i get "level 2a" in the "lev1" column etc ...

I need something like this :

```
    |   lev1    |  lev2     |   lev3
----|-----------|-----------|---------- 
    |  level 1a | level 2a  | level 3a  
    |  level 1a | level 2a  | level 3b  
    |  level 1a | level 2b  |
    |  level 1b | level 2a  |  
    |  level 1b | level 2b  |
    |  level 1d |
    |  level 1c |
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.name AS lev1,
  t2.name AS lev2,
  t3.name AS lev3,
  t4.name AS lev4
FROM matieres_test AS t1
LEFT JOIN matieres_test AS t2
  ON t2.parent = t1.id
LEFT JOIN matieres_test AS t3
  ON t3.parent = t2.id
LEFT JOIN matieres_test AS t4
  ON t4.parent = t3.id
WHERE t1.parent IS NULL
ORDER BY lev1, lev2, lev3, lev4;
```

You have to add a `IS NULL` check for the t1.parent. With the given `ORDER BY` clause you can sort the result correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all you need to do is to constrain the query so that the `lev1` records has `null` as `parent`:

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM matieres_test AS t1
LEFT JOIN matieres_test AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
LEFT JOIN matieres_test AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
LEFT JOIN matieres_test AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
WHERE t1.parent IS NULL -- add this condition
-- and an optional ORDER BY clause if you need the result in a specific order...
```

After adding the `where` clause the result becomes:

```
lev1       lev2       lev3       lev4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
level 1a   level 2a   level 3a   NULL
level 1a   level 2a   level 3b   NULL
level 1a   level 2b   NULL       NULL
level 1b   level 2a   NULL       NULL
level 1b   level 2b   NULL       NULL
level 1c   NULL       NULL       NULL
level 1d   NULL       NULL       NULL
```

Comment: Without adding an order by clause the result will look different. The first row for example give level 1b, level 2b, null, null

Comment: @mxlse Yes, without any explicit ordering the resulting set will most likely be unordered.

Comment: thanks you answer work for me. I accept the other answer because he have less point ;)